# Enviar mensaje customizado a Whatsapp a traves de inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, whatsapp

Buenas lo que ocurre es que estoy tratando de obtener los datos de unos input text, date y time para modificar un mensaje personalizado que se le va a enviar por Whatsapp a cierta persona sin embargo el boton no me funciona simplemente no me redirecciona a la pagina con el mensaje personalizado como podria hacerlo?

Este es mi codigo :

```
<a onclick="wap();" id="Messa_wap" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=34695685920&text=hola,%20¿qué%20tal%20estás?" class="boxed-btn submit-btn" value="click">Send Message</a>
```

Ese es el boton que envia el mensaje inicialmente sin embargo al hacer click no llama la funcion y se redirecciona inmediatamente a la pagina con el otro mensaje.

Esta es la funcion:

```
<script >
    function wap()
    {
        let nombre = document.getElementById("nam_t").value;
        let tel = document.getElementById("nam_p").value;
        let correo = document.getElementById("nam_em").value;
        let fecha = document.getElementById("nam_dat").value;
        let hor = document.getElementById("nam_ho").value;
        let mens = document.getElementById("nam_mess").value;

        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML= "<a id='Messa_wap' href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1"+tel+"&text=Hi,%20"+nombre+"you%20have%20scheduled%20an%20appointment%20on%20"+fecha+"%20with%20the%20following%20instructions%20"+mens+"' class='boxed-btn submit-btn' value='click'>Send Message</a>";

    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>formulario wtp</h1>
    <form id="frm">
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
      <input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required />
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
      <input type="date" id="date" required />
      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</html>




const frm = document.querySelector("#frm");

frm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const frm = event.target;
  const formData = {
    name: frm.name.value,
    phone: frm.phone.value,
    email: frm.email.value,
    date: frm.date.value
  };

  const URL = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${formData.phone}&text=Hi, ${formData.name}%20you%20have%20scheduled%20an%20appointment%20on%20${formData.date}%20with%20the%20following%20instructions%20&source=&data=`;

  window.open(URL, "_blank");
});
```